# How to compare to HEX 0x value

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I'm creating a view where I would like to set one of the fields depending on a particular Byte from a BLOB. Code goes like:

```
CASE HEX(SUBSTRING(data, 1, 1))
    WHEN 0X55 THEN 3
    WHEN 0X56 THEN 5
END AS fieldname,
```

But apparently it's not possible to compare to HEX 0x, like I'm doing.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try either `0x55` or `55`.  I'm pretty sure the `x` in a "hex literal" needs to be lower case.  Also, I think the `HEX()` function returns a "hex string" of just the value.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex